# PHP how to access

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following array.  I am just showing number 0 to reduce the post lenght.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => vector
            [id] => somecoolid
            [name] => aa_filename
            [center] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 139.34831290409
                    [1] => 38.282884929937
                    [2] => 2
                )

            [created] => 2022-12-04T01:42:56.051Z
            [modified] => 2022-12-04T01:44:47.634Z
            [visibility] => private
            [description] => some description
            [filesize] => 260139
            [status] => available
            [tileset_precisions] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [10m] => 1608318
                )

            [created_by_client] => CI
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
     ...snip...
```

The entire array is assigned to $getBodyTilesets. To access most of the data, I use the following loop;

```
<?php foreach ($getBodyTilesets as $getBodyTileset) :  ?>

<?= $getBodyTileset->id ?>
<?= $getBodyTileset->type ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->name ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->center[0] ?> <?= $getBodyTileset->center[1] ?> <?= $getBodyTileset->center[2] ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->created ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->modified ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->visibility ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->description ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->filesize ?></td>
<?= $getBodyTileset->status ?></td>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I cannot understand how to access `tileset_precisions`. The above says `[10m]` but this data will always change to something different like `[5m]` or `[3cm]` or `[71.m]` etc.  How would one best access that data pls?

Comment: `this data will always change to something different like [5m] or [3cm] or [71.m] etc`...yuk. Can you ask whoever created this data to make a more sensible structure? P.S. If you decoded this from JSON, you could ask json_decode to decode it as an associative array, that would make this easier. Failing that, you probably need to [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+get+all+object+properties), or you can try casting the object to an array on-demand

Answer (score 2):

When `tileset_precisions` always has **one** element, then

```
<?= array_values((array)$getBodyTileset->tileset_precisions)[0] ?></td>
```

or

```
<?= current((array)$getBodyTileset->tileset_precisions) ?></td>
```

If you  also want the key e.g `10m`:

```
<?= key((array)$getBodyTileset->tileset_precisions) ?></td>
```

Comment: @ADyson I thought `data` is refered to the value of the element.

Comment: Sorry I misread, already deleted that comment!